# How to run a file in SublimeREPL?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

To run a file via the SublimeREPL plugin, I select 'Tools' -> 'SublimeREPL' -> 'Eval In REPL' -> 'File'

When I select 'File' nothing happens. How do I configure Sublime Text 2 to use a specified REPL ?

Comment: Could you specify with which language does this happen? :)

Comment: @wuub it happens for all languages, so it does not mater what file type is open, be it .java or .scala etc the resuls is same

Answer (score 0):

I think SublimeREPL only supports this for python files, if you look [here](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#readme) you'll see that it is only under the python heading that this feature is mentioned.

#### Python

- Launch python in local or remote(1) virtualenv.
- `Quickly run selected script or launch PDB.`
- Use SublimeText2 Python console with history and multiline input.

Besides if you press(on windows) `shift+ctrl+p` you'll see that if you type `repl current` it will say:
`SublimeREPL: Python - RUN Current File`

As the only alternative, well except for PDB.

Answer (score 0):

As @daniel-figueroa states, SublimeREPL only runs Python code as far as I'm aware.

If you are just trying to *run* Python with SublimeREPL, try:

`Tools` -> `SublimeREPL` -> `Python` -> `Python` -> `RUN current file`

Alternatively, if you're actually intending to evaluate with SublimeREPL, the plugin author, @wuub explains and offers a solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12921385/3185548).